# package.json test script: reg. expression to enter deeper directories?

Tags: node.js, testing, npm, mocha.js, package.json

I have a `test` script at my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "npm run build && mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register --recursive src/**/*.spec.ts"
  },
  ...
}
```

That should be running every test found inside the `/src` directory, that has the following structure:

[image]

But the `src/**/*.spec.ts` regular expression is running only `camel.spec.ts` tests, but not the other ones that are found in deeper directories (`bactrian.spec.ts`, `domestic.spec.ts`, `dromedary.spec.ts`).

Has anyone experienced this, or knows the correct expression I should be using?

Comment: i just set up a test directory structure and `mocha --recursive src/**/*.spec.ts` works for me, and it grabs the tests within the subdirectories. what version of mocha are you using?

Comment: I'm using `"mocha": "^3.0.0"`

Comment: What's your OS and default system shell (i.e. bash or cmd.exe)?

Comment: @RyanZim using z-shell (Mac)

Comment: `"test": "npm run build && mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register --recursive 'src/**/*.spec.ts'"` did it!! Notice the simple quotes!